# Does 'an epiphany hit me' sound right?

Tags: usage, idioms

People say 'I have an epiphany' but I want it shorter and sound more sudden.

Does 'an epiphany hit me' sound right?

Comment: [Google books](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22an+epiphany+hit%22&tbm=bks) shows more than a hundred instances of "an epiphany hit", so you wouldn't be the first to say it.

Comment: "Hit" is an action an epiphany is not likely to perform, unless it's a really hard one...  So, saying "then it hit me" is an admission of the impact produced.

Answer (score 2):

Epiphany is a sudden realization of a truth. So "Sudden" already emphasizes the impact of the phrase. **I had an epiphany** is actually the perfect way to use it. You do not want to over-emphasize a phrase.